# Why is the onclick event for my input button not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events

The `onclick`-function of the `<button>` in the following code is **not** working.

I want to show a ***SAVE*** button when the editable area is clicked. Then the button's `onclick` function should display an **alert** but this is not working.

```css
.views-submit-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.views-exposed-widget:focus-within+.views-submit-button {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <title></title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container">
   <div class="views-exposed-widget">
     <div contenteditable id="editable-text-name">
    Editable text here.
   </div>
   </div>
   <div class="views-submit-button">
     <button id="save-button" type="button" onclick="alert('button clicked.')" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Save</button>
   </div> 
 </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe because your editable content lost focus already? Maybe set the focus on the views-exposed-widget, and the button as part of it?

Comment: It's because the button is never actually clicked. When your editable area loses focus, the views-submit-button disappears.

Comment: @godblessstrawberry : yes I need 'contenteditable' to change it using the button's onclick function.

Comment: Your button is unclickable, because of the`.views-submit-button {visibility: hidden;}` rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your implementation css hides the button before the actual click happens

here's JS solution that hides button after alert triggered or by timeout when your `contenteditable` loses its focus

alternatively you can use `opacity` instead of `visibility` in css so it will remain clickable but this feels hacky, someone could click that accidentally so I would not recommend

```css
.views-submit-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="views-exposed-widget">
    <div tabindex="1" contenteditable id="editable-text-name" onfocusin="document.getElementById('save-button').style.visibility = 'visible'" onfocusout="setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('save-button').style.visibility = 'hidden'}, 100)">
      Editable text here.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="views-submit-button">
    <button id="save-button" type="button" onclick="alert('button clicked.');this.style.visibility = 'hidden';" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Save</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the button to be hidden when the editable area lose focus.

Comment: @Ismail simpliest solution I can think of is to use `setTimeout` on `focusout` event, not sure how bad is that though. added that to answer

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code and add input event to your contenteditable element

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var isEditClicked = false;

  document.getElementById("editable-text-name").addEventListener("input", function() {
    $(".views-submit-button").css("visibility", "visible");
  }, false);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>


  <style>
    .views-submit-button {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .views-exposed-widget:focus-within+.views-submit-button {
      visibility: visible;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="views-exposed-widget">
      <div contenteditable id="editable-text-name">
        Editable text here.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="views-submit-button">
      <button id="save-button" type="button" onclick="alert('button clicked.')" class="btn btn-outline-dark">Save</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes it works for me...His next requirement is not fullfilled where in he wants to hide the button after editable text looses focus...Practically I am not sure of the requirement he could achieve using above...

Answer (score -1):

I have changed the CSS. You need to change the CSS as per your requirements. But this is the way which you can follow to meet your needs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
    <style>

        .button {
            display: none;
        }

            input:hover + .button, .button:hover {
                display: inline-block;
            }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="small-4 columns">
        <input type="text" value="Hi" />
        <button class="button" onclick="alert('Hello');">Click Me</button>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Down voters can please update me with a better way ? Did you ever tried with Run Code Snippet

Comment: it behaves inconsistently, sometimes button disappears before you can hover on it. regardless of focus

Answer (score -2):

The button is hidden that's why you don't see him. In your style change .views-submit-button to visible and button appears. In your wrapper div class name is .views-submit-button so that's why button is hidden by default.

```
.views-submit-button {
          visibility: hidden;
}
```

You can use toggle method to manipulate button's visibility after click

Answer (score -3):

The css execute first. you may use javascript to control it